# Is this a spontaneous symmetry-breaking?

Tags: dynamical-systems, symmetry, bifurcation

I have a system of equations:

\begin{cases}
f\left(x_{1}\right)+f\left(x_{2}\right)+P=0\\
\\
g\left(x_{1}\right)+g\left(x_{2}\right)=0
\end{cases}

where $f,g$ are some functions, $\boldsymbol{x}=\left[\begin{array}{c}x_{1}\\x_{2}\end{array}\right]$ is the unknown, and $P$ is a parameter that I want to vary. Let's say that for $P<P^{*}$ the solution of my equation is a stable $\underline{\boldsymbol{x}}=\left[\begin{array}{c}\alpha\left(P\right)
 \\\alpha\left(P\right)
 \end{array}\right]$, while for $P>P^{*}$ the solution $\underline{\boldsymbol{x}}$ becomes unstable, and I also got two new stable solutions $\overline{\boldsymbol{x}}=\left[\begin{array}{c}\beta\left(P\right)
 \\\gamma\left(P\right)
 \end{array}\right]$, $\overline{\overline{\boldsymbol{x}}}=\left[\begin{array}{c}\gamma\left(P\right)\\\beta\left(P\right)\end{array}\right]$ (here $\alpha\left(\cdot\right)$, $\beta\left(\cdot\right)$ and $\gamma\left(\cdot\right)$ are functions that depend on $f\left(\cdot\right)$ and $g\left(\cdot\right))$.

Clearly **the system of equations** is always (i.e. $\forall P$) symmetric under exchange of $x_{1}$ and $x_{2}$, but **the solutions** (i.e. $\overline{\boldsymbol{x}}$ and $\overline{\overline{\boldsymbol{x}}}$) are not for $P>P^{*}$. Moreover, for $P>P^{*}$, in numerical simulations the solution converge to one between $\overline{\boldsymbol{x}}$ and $\overline{\overline{\boldsymbol{x}}}$. In other terms, I think this is a pitchfork bifurcation. Is this an example of **spontaneous** symmetry-breaking? Or just a symmetry breaking?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nobody? This is a trivial question. I think to know the correct answer, but I'd need a confirmation. Clearly I don't want to influence eventual answers from other users.

Comment: what is spontaneous symmetry breaking and why are $-2f(0)$ and $-2f(1)$ the only possible values for $P$ ?

Comment: Thanks mercio. I oversimplified the description of the problem in order to get an answer. I have just edited my text, now it should be fixed.

Comment: It sure looks spontaneous to me, because there is no explicit term breaking the symmetry, but then all I know is the Wikipedia article I just looked up. You might find more people who know about symmetry breaking at [the physics site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thanks Rahul, I agree completely. I'm not an expert of the topic, and like you, unfortunately I only know the content of the Wiki article. I'll follow your suggestion!